# xamarin ios app is only run with don't link behaviour. when other linker behaviour its crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, linker, linker-errors

xamarin form ios app is crash when the linker behavior in not don't link. 
i am adding a framework(sdk) through binding project.using of the framework the app is crash in other linker behavior like link all and link framework only.
i think preserve the attribute.but i don't know what and how to preserve the whole framework. should i preserve the api definition of the framework or any thing else. there are any other solution for that crash problem. 
i must use the link framework behavior only because submit of app.if i use linker behavior don't link it add the health kit. 
what should i do plz help

Comment: What are the details of the crash (iOS native|.net exception/stacktrace?)

Comment: What external assemblies do you use in your project ?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone builds are always AOT (Ahead of Time) compiled since the iOS iPhone runtime will not allow dynamic code generation so your Xam.iOS code has to be fully compiled to machine code before deploying to an iPhone.

It might be a case where the xamarin compiler did not find the class and did not bundle it in a IPA which is causing the crash.

If you want to use the "Link All" linker option, then you are going to have to do the work to make sure you are preserving all needed types from any third party libraries that you may be referencing only via reflection since the linker will strip out any code in non-Xamarin-framework assemblies that is not statically referenced in your app code.

You can find more information [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/150907/strange-build-behavior-for-release-configuration)